# Removing quotes OR including quotes when using append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, quotations

I have a variable, PRODUCT_CUSTOM_1_ and PRODUCT_NAME_ . This is suppose to grab the product options from the html that is being displayed. We have a few products that contain quotations, " and '. When we grab these strings and post them elsewhere, it cuts off at the ". I either need the " removed or included within us posting it elsewhere.

How can I remove or include the " and ' from the two variables into my hidden form iwantCheckoutForm?

An example of a product name: 1/8" x 40' roll of tape
An example of the custom option: 1/8" black, 1/4" red

```
var BongoCheckout = {insertForm: function() {

var custom =new Array;
for(i=0;i< qtys.length ;i++){
        custom[i]="";
        for(j=0;j< $($("td.ys_itemInfo")[i]).children().children().length; j++){
             custom[i]= custom[i]+"   "+$($($("td.ys_itemInfo")[i]).children().children()[j]).text();
        }

$("#iwantCheckoutForm").append('<input type="hidden" name="PRODUCT_ID_'+(i+1)+'" value="'+codes[i]+'">');
$("#iwantCheckoutForm").append('<input type="hidden" name="PRODUCT_NAME_'+(i+1)+'" value="'+items[i]+'">');
$("#iwantCheckoutForm").append('<input type="hidden" name="PRODUCT_PRICE_'+(i+1)+'" value="'+price[i]+'">');
$("#iwantCheckoutForm").append('<input type="hidden" name="PRODUCT_Q_'+(i+1)+'" value="'+qtys[i]+'">');
$("#iwantCheckoutForm").append('<input type="hidden" name="PRODUCT_CUSTOM_1_'+(i+1)+'" value="'+custom[i]+'" /> ');

if (per_item_shipping) {
$('form[name="iwantCheckoutForm"]').append('<input type="hidden" name="PRODUCT_SHIPPING_'+(i+1)+'" value="'+shipping_cost.toString()+'"> ');
} else {
$('form[name="iwantCheckoutForm"]').append('<input type="hidden" name="PRODUCT_SHIPPING_'+(i+1)+'" value="'+shipping_cost_breakdown+'"> ');
}
}}
```

I know that this is a duplicate question sort of, but i couldn't quite figure out how to implement the 10+ suggestions into my current script. I just can't seem to include the regex argument, without the script from breaking. I tried to add it within the for loop.

```
        for(j=0;j< $($("td.ys_itemInfo")[i]).children().children().length; j++){
             custom[i]= custom[i]+"   "+$($($("td.ys_itemInfo")[i]).children().children()[j]).text(custom.replace(/\"/g, ""));
        }
```

Blame that on me still being a n00b, and blame that on my ADD. I suppose I just don't know where I need to add .replace(/\"/g, "") as this code seems to be working for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating HTML code for an element, just create the element and set the value. That elliminates all problems with escaping characters:

```
$("#iwantCheckoutForm").append(
  $('<input>', { type: 'hidden', name: 'PRODUCT_NAME_'+(i+1) }).val(items[i])
);
```

Comment: Wow, such quick responses. I am going to test this method out first, as this makes the most sense on how to implement. I will report back, if this did it in a couple hours. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use function

```
function makeInput(name,value) {
 var tmp = $('<input type="hidden" />');
 tmp.attr('name', name);
 tmp.val(value);
 return tmp;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/5EX3y/2/

Comment: I did not test this, but trust that it would have worked. I just am a beginner and wasn't quite sure where I would have put this. Thanks though.